# Using Sed on numbers with negative - signs

Tags: sed

I have a csv file and in a number of fields there are floating point numbers where the negative at the end of the number, I want these to be altered so as to have the minus/negative symbol at the front.

ie

```
23.4954-,23.12-

0.23-,16.5453

2495.1-,12,134-
```

I would like those to read

```
-23.4954,-23.12

-0.23,16.5453

-2495.1,-12,134
```

Out of 20 columns and a few thousand rows, there are probably about 80 instances per file, but it is a real pain to just go and replace them

I was hoping to use `sed` on the files to alter them if possible.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: was this `12,134-` a typo? (`12.134-`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
sed -ri 's/([0-9.]+)-/-\1/g' filepath
```

`-r` (`--regexp-extended`) - allows using extended regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions

`-i` - option which allows to change file in place

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `sed` command:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9.]+)-/-\1/g' file
```

This moves the `-` sign before a number composed of `0-9.` characters.

Comment: If your `sed` doesn't have the `-E` option, try `-r` instead, or use the portable script `'s/\([0-9.][0-9.]*\)-/-\1/g'` with no option.